# Flutter - TextFormField - calling Future from TextInputFormatter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a TextFormField that formats a phone number as you type it. I am trying to use the libphonenumber package to do this, but the method it provides returns a `Future<String>`, not a String. I can't figure out how to make it work.

My input field looks like this:

```
TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: "Phone Number",
    ),
    controller: _textController,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[_PhoneFormatter('US')],
  )
```

and the formatter code looks like this:

```
import 'package:libphonenumber/libphonenumber.dart';

class _PhoneFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  final String _countryCode;

  _PhoneFormatter(this._countryCode);

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(oldPhone, newPhone) {
    final phoneNumber = PhoneNumberUtil.formatAsYouType(
        phoneNumber: newPhone.text, isoCode: _countryCode);
    return TextEditingValue(
        text: phoneNumber,
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: phoneNumber.length));
  }
}
```

but I get the error:

> The argument type `'Future<String'` can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

I tried to re-write it with "async/await":

```
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(oldPhone, newPhone) async {
    final phoneNumber = await PhoneNumberUtil.formatAsYouType(
        phoneNumber: newPhone.text, isoCode: _countryCode);
    return TextEditingValue(
        text: phoneNumber,
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: phoneNumber.length));
  }
```

but I then get the error:

> Functions marked 'async' must have a return type assignable to 'Future'.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to find a solution to my problem. I found another package (intl_phone_number_input) that utilized the same feature of libphonenumber, and I saw how they did it (thanks to oluwatobi.ogunye@bankly.ng). They require an async callback method as a parameter to the TextInputFormatter, and then call it during the edit processing. In another million years I would not have figured this out on my own...

Here is my updated formatter code:

```
import 'package:libphonenumber/libphonenumber.dart';

class _PhoneFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  final String _countryCode;
  final void Function(TextEditingValue value) onPhoneFormatted;

  _PhoneFormatter(this._countryCode, {@required this.onPhoneFormatted});

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(oldPhone, newPhone) {
    _formatPhone(newPhone.text.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^\d\+]+'), ''))
        .then((String phone) {
      onPhoneFormatted(TextEditingValue(
          text: phone,
          selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: phone.length)));
    });
    return newPhone;
  }

  Future<String> _formatPhone(String phoneNumber) async {
    try {
      String formattedPhoneNumber = await PhoneNumberUtil.formatAsYouType(
          phoneNumber: phoneNumber, isoCode: _countryCode);
      return formattedPhoneNumber ?? phoneNumber;
    } on Exception {
      return phoneNumber;
    }
  }
}
```

and my input field that utilizes it:

```
final _countryCode = 'US'

TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Phone Number",
  ),
  controller: _textController,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
    _PhoneFormatter(
      _countryCode,
      onPhoneFormatted: (TextEditingValue value) {
        setState(() {
          _textController.value = value;
        });
      },
    )
  ],
)
```

Seems to work great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [mask_text_input_formatter](https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter) package for the flexible phone formatting:

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Phone Number",
  ),
  controller: _textController,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
  inputFormatters: [phoneFormatter()],
)

//...

MaskTextInputFormatter phoneFormatter(){
  return MaskTextInputFormatter(mask: '+#-###-###-####', filter: { "#": RegExp(r'[0-9]') });
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. The error I get now is: '_PhoneFormatter.formatEditUpdate' ('Future<TextEditingValue> Function(TextEditingValue, TextEditingValue)') isn't a valid override of 'TextInputFormatter.formatEditUpdate' ('TextEditingValue Function(TextEditingValue, TextEditingValue)').

Comment: @ScottSmith indeed. So, here we have two problems: we can't override method due to `Future`, and we can't call `PhoneNumberUtil.formatAsYouType` due to `await`. Check my updated answer, I suggested method which uses only pure Flutter package without native Java calls

Comment: Thank you, I see that would work. But I need to support all the country codes and the different formats of each (my example was just 'US'), so I'm hoping to utilize Google's libphonenumber or equivalent.

Comment: @ScottSmith I understood you. Unfortunately, I don't have appropriate idea for you now.